# $\mathbb CG$-modules proposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Another plea for a starting point please!

I know what all of the terminology means, but a starting point would be greatly appreciated!

Suppose that $V$ is simple of degree $>1$ and $x\in V$. Prove that $\sum_{g\in G} g.x =0$.

Thanks in advance!

Andy.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Prove that $\Bbb{C}\cdot ((\sum_G g)\cdot x)$ is a sub-$\Bbb C G$-module of $V$ of dimension $1$ for every $x\in V$. Since $V$ is simple of dimension greater than 1, what can you deduce?

Comment: Thanks Nitrogen, just one follow up question: what do you mean by $\mathbb{C}\dot$ above?

Comment: @andrew1601 It means the $\Bbb{C}$-vector subspace of $V$ with basis $\{(\sum g)\cdot x\}$. And the claim is that this subspace is actually a submodule.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. I have done a bit of work with that, and know how to finish the proof once I have shown that it is a submodule. I think I am nearly at the end, but unsure how to proceed. I have typed it up in TeXPaste because comments don't support TeX and you can find it here http://www.texpaste.com/n/p0q3d9kd If you could take a look and get back to me, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks. Andy